# ensure a create action only happens once in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method which checks to see if the current stock level of a certain product associated with a job is below zero. If the product level does fall below zero the method in question creates a comment reminding a user. I am calling the method from my controller index action.

```
    def check_total_quantities(job_products, job)
      job_products.each do |job_product|
        if job.not_confirmed? && job_product.product.available_quantity < 0 
          stock_reminder = job.comments.build(body: "There is a stock issue with product '#{job_product.product.title}' in job #{job.title} for client #{job.client.title}. Stock levels might be too low to use this product on this job.",
                          admin_id: job.admin.id,
                          important: true,
                          public: true)
          stock_reminder.save
          return true
        end
      end
    end
```

However, if I reload the page the comment gets repeated. What ways are available to me to avoid such a thing occurring? I only really want it to happen once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Active Record's [find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by) method. So after your if condition you can check if a comment of that type for that specific job already exists, if not, save a new one (what you're doing now). You can do both steps in one command. Pretty cool.

```
job.find_or_create_by(job_id: job.id, type: :stock_below_zero)
```

I think it's necessary to have a defining attribute in comments like **type** or something, or a flag `stock_below_zero` saying if that comment is under that condition or not (or visualized or not) to differentiate between other comments for that same job.

Comment: But what if there are other products that fall below zero?